# Hidden phrase puzzle

Tags: word, rebus

[image]

Stuck on the first puzzle. It could be ridiculously obvious
Solved the other two.

Comment: "Not bad" is the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: I dunno, 'bad' crossed out being 'not bad' isn't much of a 'mindbender'. ;) The other 2 pictures aren't *that* explicit. I'd sooner guess ['bad-off'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bad_off), maybe?

Answer (score 10):

The first is simply

> Not bad - its bad crossed out as Forklift said in the comments

The second is obviously

> On second thought(s) - 'on' on the second thoughts (assuming this is a British English book then it will be thoughts, if it is AmE then it will be thought)

The last one is

> [Bits and bobs](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bits_and_bobs) - a list of bits and a collection of people who have the first name 'bob'

Comment: I've never heard the second one as a plural before.

Comment: @feelinferrety really? I've never heard it singular :P Might be a English/American thing - like math/maths

Comment: (1) I don’t have a better answer, but I agree with [Walt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/53858/19765#comment166436_53858) — it’s too easy compared to the other two.  (2a) I, also, have never heard this as a plural before (in the US).  (2b) Bad puzzle!  It’s actually “**on**” on (the second box); I believe that this doesn’t work well. (3) I’ve never heard of this phrase at all.  You might as well say that it’s “numbers added to celebrities”.

Comment: @PeregrineRook 1 seems to be a warm up, which is probably why it's easier. I did think that it was wrong to have the word 'on' because that makes it 'on on second thought(s)' 3, really?! Surprising, it's a [famous phrase](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bits_and_bobs), same as odds and ends, bits and pieces, etc.